# windows batch Iterate tokens in a for loop

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, token, loops

How to iterate through tokens in a for loop in Windows batch scripting?

I'm writing a script that allows the user to search a file and print out the parent directory for that file.  So far I can get a full path from a file name but I just need the parent directory.   Works fine but would like a more efficient way of iterating through the tokens.

Here is a snip-it of what I have.  The file variable is the file to be searched and thePath variable is the full path to the file.

```
fOR /F "tokens=1-25 delims=\" %%i IN ("!thePath!") DO (

    if %%j equ %file% set theParent= %%i
    if %%k equ %file% set theParent= %%j
    if %%l equ %file% set theParent= %%k
    if %%m equ %file% set theParent= %%l
    if %%n equ %file% set theParent= %%m
    if %%o equ %file% set theParent= %%n
    if %%p equ %file% set theParent= %%o
    if %%q equ %file% set theParent= %%p
    if %%r equ %file% set theParent= %%q
    if %%s equ %file% set theParent= %%r
    if %%t equ %file% set theParent= %%s
    if %%u equ %file% set theParent= %%t
    if %%v equ %file% set theParent= %%u
    if %%w equ %file% set theParent= %%v
    if %%x equ %file% set theParent= %%w
    if %%y equ %file% set theParent= %%x
    if %%z equ %file% set theParent= %%y


)
echo The parent directory is: %theParent%
```

Answer (score 5):

Your approach cannot work reliably because a file may share the same name as one of its parent folders.

There is no need to iterate FOR /F tokens. You can get the parent folder directly using a simple FOR :-)

```
for %%F in ("!thePath!\..") do set "theParent=%%~nxF"
echo The parent directory is: !theParent!
```

*Note - `theParent` will be undefined (empty) if the file is in the root directory.*

Comment: +1 For Simple and Efficient answer!  **Short Explanation:** the `\..` tells the command line interpreter to retrieve the parent directory of the specified path.  The `for` loop only runs one pass and is used to just convert the path into a variable with modifiers `%%~nxF`.

Comment: Awesome!  That is exactly what I was looking for.  I actually tried the for loop you have here but it was only returning the file name.  The \.. is the key here. Thanks.